# writing sysdig output to a file

Tags: bash, stdout, stderr, nohup, sysdig

I want to check my users commands on my server for a period of time so I use sysdig command with nohup. I want to write output to a file like so:

```
# nohup sysdig -c spy_users 1>>/path/to/true 2>>/path/to/false &
```

But result is not written to file realtime. Any idea?

Comment: If you kill your `sysdig`, it flushes the buffer and you will see the output in the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably it is being buffered. Try to set the buffering to line-buffer or deactivete it completely:

```
nohup stdbuf -oL -eL sysdig -c spy_users 1>>/path/to/true 2>>/path/to/false &
```